# JavaScript queryselector with same class must click twice

Tags: javascript, html, click

I have two items that are doing the same; when clicked, they will open and when clicked again, they will collapse. It works, but it doesn't work how I want it to work.

When you click an item, it opens. **When I click the second item (which hasn't opened yet), it doesn't work at the first click**, because it still thinks I am busy with the second click. I do understand that, but I don't know how to fix that in pure JavaScript.

Do I have to add an `AddEventListener` or something? So what I want is that I can click on all of the items, opening it the first time I click (and collapse it when clicked again), instead of clicking twice.

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="area">Test title
   <div class="some content" style="display: none">blablbala</div>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/nb1ao39k/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should apply the business logic to `this` element but not to the first `.area` element:

```
function areaCollapse() {
    var next = this.firstElementChild;

    if (this.classList.contains("open")) {
        next.style.display = "none";
        this.classList.remove("open");
    } else {
        next.style.display = "block";
        this.classList.add("open");
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nb1ao39k/1/

Comment: Very good answer, thank you. I gave you an upvote. This solves the problem... and it is better written than mine code. Thank you. Will accept it.